# What are the statistical implications of assigning treatment and control in time series study under 2 different approaches?

Tags: sampling, econometrics, experiment-design, panel-data

I have a project wherein my group wants to measure the effect of counseling at-risk students on their academic outcomes.

There are 1,000 students who will be enrolled during the current academic term. Resources (such as the counselors) are limited, so we can only use a `subset` of these. My boss says that we have enough funding to take the `top 6 deciles` (600 students with the worst grades) and randomly assign 50% to `control` and 50% to `treatment`.

The 50% who receive `treatment` will be contacted by advisers, whereas the 50% in `control` will not.

However, this is not just a `pre/post` study. Instead, we will have `k` instances of outreach (i.e. `treatment`) during the term, where `k` is between 2 and 5.

My boss laid out 2 different approaches that we could take and asked which I recommend. I'm want to be sure that I understand the statistical implications of each approach, so that I can make a well-informed recommendation. Here are the two choices:

1. Randomly assign `treatment` and `control` to all students at the beginning of the study, select the top 6 `deciles`, at `k = 1`, and have the counselors talk to these same students at each of the `k` time periods. Within the 6 `deciles`, about 300 should be in `treatment` and about 300 in `control` and those groups will be compared at the end of the study.
2. Randomly assign `treatment` and `control` to all students at the beginning of the study, select the top 6 `deciles`, at `k = 1`, and have counselors reach out to the approximate 50% in the `treatment` group, just as in option #1. **BUT** at `k = 2` and each subsequent time period, recalculate the top 6 `deciles`. Many of the students will be the same, but some of those who were in the top 6 `deciles` at `k = 1` may be in the bottom 4 `deciles` at `k = 2, k = 3, etc`. Assignment to `treatment` or `control` won't change, but inclusion in the subset of the population will change for some students.

My intuition is that option #1 will me more simplistic and thus shield us from potential bias that we may introduce. On the other hand, #2 would give us a `larger sample` with more `identifying variation`, though not all `treatment` students will receive treatment at each of the `k` time periods.

In some ways, it seems like #2 could actually allow for a more in-depth analysis, because we could not only look at the effect of `treatment`, but also the `frequency` and `timing` of treatment, so that we could potentially pick up on `diminishing marginal returns` to treatment or variations in the effectiveness of `treatment` in terms of timing (i.e. outreach by counselors could be more effective earlier on or at the end of the course).

Would #2 introduce bias or create other statistical complications? If so, should I rule out #2 or would it require additional statistical controls to account for the (semi-)`endogenous` changes in the composition of the 6 deciles?

Comment: #2 would definitely introduce statistical complications, but not necessarily anything you can't handle. Depends on what those additional insights would be worth to you! If power is a concern, there's something to be said for keeping everyone split into only two groups, but this would seem to give you a less nuanced picture of any relationship between the effect of treatment and its timing or continuity.